# whats wrong in my zend url helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-studio

here is my code below of my `module.config` page

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/photos[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Photos\Controller\Photos',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

and in my controller page

```
public function uploadAction()
{

    //die('uploading page');
  $this->layout('layout/index');

    return array();
}
```

`die works fine`

my front end page code is

this is the page iam trying to link to any other pages.....

```
 `<?php echo $this->url('photos',array('action' => 'upload_done')); ?>`
```

iam getting an error

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Route with name "photos" not found' in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php echo $this->url('album',array('action' => 'upload_done')); ?>
```

The url plugin takes the *name* of the route, which in your example is "album" despite the url route being "photos"

(You could also rename the route as "photos" and stick with your original url plugin example)